# How to ignore INSERT if Database already has the values, but still get the ID?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to **ignore an INSERT query if** the two values, Answer1Text and Answer2Text are already in the database, **but still get the id** (called AnswerID (Primary Key) from the row? How can I do this?

My code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO answers (Answer1Text, Answer2Text) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $text1, $text2);
$stmt->execute();
$answerid = $stmt->insert_id;
```

Table of importance:

**answers:** AnswerID(PK), Answer1Text, Answer2Text

I have tried looking at `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I neither understand how to use it, nor do I think it is the right choice.

Comment: no insert, no id, so you would have to do a select query

Comment: See my answer below. Minor point: I've read a lot of Stack Overflow PHP questions today, and you're the first I've seen to use bound parameters correctly - thank you for being sane! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to query your database first using a `SELECT` query: does the data already exist? If so, pull out the ID and use that in place of the insert ID; if not, insert a new row. You're right: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is wrong for this.

Comment: That worked wonderfully, thank you for your answer! I am very happy that you say I'm using it correctly since I am very new at using them and need them to be correct for my exam project.